# Hybris HMC: adding a button to ToolBarChip / Editor window next to the save button

Tags: button, toolbar, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm working with Hybris 5.6 and I'm trying to add a button in the editor area right next to the save/reload/delete buttons.

How can I add a button to the ToolBarChip like in the example below?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite possible to add a new action (label) to the toolbar of HMC, *however it's not so recommended as it may result some issues while the migration*.

1. First, add the following snippet to your **/hmc.xml :

```xml
<type name="AbstractOrder" mode="append">

  <organizer mode="append" > 
     <editor>
        <tab name="payment_and_delivery" position="2" mode="append">

           <section name="deliveryadministration" mode="append" >
              <table>
                 <tr>
                    <td width="16px">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <!-- here is the interesting part -->
                       <action type="item"
                               classname="com.foo.bar.MyNewAction" 
                               name="action.my_new_action"
                               toolbaricon="my_new_action"
                               icon="images/icons/my_new_action_icon.gif"
                               autosave="true"
                               showtoolbarlabel="true"
                               hidebutton="true"
                             />
                    </td>

                 </tr>
              </table>
           </section>

        </tab>
     </editor>
  </organizer>

</type>
```

2. Then, define the new action to be performed when the new label is clicked :
   Add a new class called `MyNewAction.java` that extends from `ItemAction` and implement the method `ActionResult perform(ActionEvent event)` :

```java
public MyNewAction extends ItemAction {

    @Override
    public ActionResult perform(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws JaloBusinessException {

        //what the new action should do here ...

    }
}
```

**Note** : you could override other interesting methods to be triggers while the action is possessing like : `boolean needConfirmation()` or `String getConfirmationMessage()` ...

The result would be like this :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works great :) I just have some questions: why `payment_and_delivery` and `deliveryadministration`? and what does `position 2` means?

Comment: It means that this new `Action button` belongs to the Section : `Delivery` inside the Tab: `Payment and Delivery` it was just an example, make `hidebutton="false"` and will understand what i mean.

Comment: Okay I see. Do you know if it is possible to show the button only if something is true?

Comment: Then you need to implement one more method : `boolean isVisible(ActionEvent event) { return condition }`

Comment: I implemented that method, but it gets never called

Comment: Try `isActive(ActionEvent event)`

Comment: `isActive` is not hiding the button but disabling it. that is enough for me, thank you :)